# TestNG: How to execute several test methods in order with data supplied from DataProvider

Tags: testng, dataprovider

Is there a way to execute several test methods in order using different data from the data provider?

e.g.

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
    return new Object[][] {
        { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
        { "Anne", new Integer(37)}, 
    };
}


@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
    System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}

@Test
public void verifyData2() {
    System.out.println("Verify2");
}
```

And the output of running this would be
Cedric 36
Verify2
Anne 37
Verify2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it: use an annotation to specify which method should receive which data:

```
public class A {

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] dp(Method m) {
    if (m.getAnnotation(Different.class) != null) {
      return new Object[][] {
          new Object[] { "different-a", "different-b" },
          new Object[] { "different-c", "different-d" },
        };
      } else {
        return new Object[][] {
            new Object[] { "c", "d" },
            new Object[] { "a", "b" },
        };
      }
    }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void test1(String a, String b) {
    System.out.println("test1: " + a + " " + b);
  }

  @Different
  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void test2(String a, String b) {
    System.out.println("test2: " + a + " " + b);
  }
}
```

The annotation:

```
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
public @interface Different {}
```

The output:

```
test1: c d
test1: a b
test2: different-a different-b
test2: different-c different-d
```

Comment: Thanks Cedric. I actually found a way to do this when I scrutinized the TestNG documentation and then noticed that I can specify group-by-instances="true" to run my tests in order. Because I am following a scenario with many tests assertions and with many different data, then I use the @Factory to create the testclass instance, feeding it with different data and then run them in order.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use multiple data providers in that class?

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
    return new Object[][] {
        { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
        { "Anne", new Integer(37)}, 
    };
}

@DataProvider(name = "test2")
public Object[][] createData2() {
    return new Object[][] {
        { "Amir", new Integer(42) },
        { "Alice", new Integer(39)}, 
    };
}


@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
    System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "test2")
public void verifyData2(String n1, Integer n2) {
    System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```